# Why does the book of Proverbs portray a negative bias towards wine?

Tags: psalms, proverbs

Proverbs 4:17 KJV

> For they eat the bread of wickedness, and drink the wine of violence.

Proverbs 20:1 KJV

> Wine is a mocker, strong drink is raging: and whosoever is deceived thereby is not wise.

Proverbs 31:6 KJV

> Give strong drink unto him that is ready to perish, and wine unto those that be of heavy hearts.

Out of the eleven verses referring to wine in the book of Proverbs only one verse shows wine in the positive light whilst the rest are in the negative light.There are plenty of verses that portray wine in the positive light and that its a gift from God

Psalms 104:15 KJV

> And wine that maketh glad the heart of man, and oil to make his face to shine, and bread which strengtheneth man's heart.

Why does the author seem to display a negative bias towards wine?

Comment: Keep in mind that bread and wine were a common part of meals (compare with the salt and pepper shakers on every restaurant table today), so they were an obvious choice when making a metaphor (the most famous being during the "last supper").
¶ And also remember that many of the Proverbs were written as "*don't make your own mistakes, learn from mine*" advice, and that when people imbibe too much they *do* tend to make mistakes.

Comment: @collen ndhlovu Author must imply excesses in drinking, for otherwise it makes no sense to reject such a great thing in life as drinking wine with friends! If Bible is against this rejoicing, then it is not Bible but Koran or some teetotaler sect-manual. Drink, with friends, talk good things related to love and friendship!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did a similar comparison with how some books in the Bible speak of sex, you might notice far more warnings about the negative (if not downright dangerous) aspects of the abuse of sex, than of the positive, lovely aspects of its proper use.

It's the same with biblical points about alcohol. It warns a lot more about the negative aspects of drinking too much than of the positive, enjoyable aspects of drinking it as it should be used.

In both cases, ***this is not displaying a bias against either sex or alcohol. It is warning about the negative abuses of those God-given provisions***. Given the fact of sin in fallen humanity, both those areas of sex and alcohol are massively abused. This has been a clear fact of history over thousands of years. It should come as no surprise, then, that those who respect God's good provisions read warnings against abusing them. They heed those warnings, while those who take a light view of God's instructions for right living will dismiss them - to their cost, and the cost of others.

Answer (score 1):

Wine itself is not wicked, but people who addict to wine will turn to wicked. If wine is wicked, then it should not allow to be used in offerings, such as the drink offerings described in Ex 29:40; Lev 23:13; Deu 15:5&7.

I disagree using "bias" in the question as then the question has a "bias" towards the answer. In Bible, when it mentioned wine, it usually drew the negative consequence of it, rather the wine itself.

Proverbs 4:17 KJV
For they eat the bread of wickedness, and drink the wine of violence.

- *It implied the violence happened as if wine was drinking.*

Proverbs 20:1 KJV
Wine is a mocker, strong drink is raging: and whosoever is deceived thereby is not wise.

- *It described the consequence of drinking wine.*

Proverbs 31:6 KJV
Give strong drink unto him that is ready to perish, and wine unto those that be of heavy hearts.

- *It described only the desperate people would need wine to forget their desperation.*

In modern day we have knowledge that how the alcoholic level affect our consciousness. Looking backward to the Biblical time, if they had regulation or self control on how much alcohol they could take, God might not need to pose this image in their mind.

And we all know, even today, drunk driving is still has a strong social impact.

Answer (score 0):

The substance 'Ha-Yayin' הַיַּיִן : The-Wine in [Proverbs 20:1] produced from kosher 'Pri' פִּרְי : Fruit (from 5-yr-old Tree, Leviticus 19:23-25) had caused נֹ֖חַ Noach to become ישכר : 'inebriated' (Genesis 9:21) impairing his judgment like Eli mistakenly warned Hannah to prevent (in 1 Samuel 1:14) עַד־מָתַי תִּשְׁתַּכָּרִין הָסִירִי אֶת־**יֵינֵ**-ךְ 'Until when will you be drunk? Throw off your Wine'. -- Both accounts reveal Wine's ability to remove wisdom. So in the pursuit of wisdom, King Shlomoh שְׁלֹמֹ֣ה : Solomon writes [Proverbs 20:1] as a preventative lifestyle for kings required to give wise counsel.